# Convert time into range in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetimerangefield

I have a datetime field which displays as eg: `2019-05-13 13:01:39`.

I want this to come as `1-2pm` or `13-14pm` in SQL.

Likewise, `2019-05-03 19:31:31` should be displayed as `7-8` or `19-20`.

Is this possible in SQL using query?

Comment: Date functions vary between DBMS. Please tag your DBMS so we can answer

Comment: Yes.It can be completed,but which database are you using now?

Comment: MYSQL database is what i am using

Comment: can it be done as a part of query? because i am inserting in db in 2019-05-13 13:01:39 format and this cant be altered.I wanted the new format to be as a part of SQL query

Comment: Add 2019-05-03 00:31:31, 2019-05-03 11:31:31  and 2019-05-03 23:31:31 to your sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `EXTRACT` function of `MySql` to get any part of date or time. Visit [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for more details

```
SELECT CONCAT(EXTRACT(hour FROM yourdate) , '-' , (EXTRACT(hour FROM yourdate) + 1))
```

Comment: Here is the [real](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) documentation

Comment: Most likely the downvote was because you linked to w3schools..w3schools had very bad (outdated) information in the past it still might have they had the name w3fools or something like that.

Comment: But + operator for string concatenation will not work in MySQL.. + operator  is SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax by the way. MySQL uses `CONCAT()` for string concatenation

Comment: Updated with proper `MySql` syntax

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using DATE_FORMAT and DATE_ADD and a 24 hour clock

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT('2019-05-03 19:31:31', '%H'), '-', 
              DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2019-05-03 19:31:31', INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%H'))
```

and the same solution with a 12 hour clock

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT('2019-05-03 19:31:31', '%h'), '-',
              DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2019-05-03 19:31:31', INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%h %p'))
```

This will output

> hour
>   19-20
>   07-08 PM

Interestingly this will give the following output if time is after 11 in the evening

> hour
>   23-00
>   11-12 AM

Is this better than for instance 23-24 or is this just a bad way to display time? Maybe for the 12 hour clock it would be better to have AM/PM after each time

> 11 PM - 12 AM